# Hidden side panel menu's padding leaves it partially visible

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg

A slide-out side panel menu won't hold internal padding without being partially displayed.

I've stripped the whole site and have tried changing just about every value, but nothing over two days of searching has worked - -though I know the answer's something obvious to an experienced coder.

```css
        .sidePanelTableA {
          height: 80%;
          width: 0;
          position: fixed;
          z-index: 20;      
          top: 0;
          background-color: red;
          overflow-x: hidden;
        }

        #mysidePanelTableA  {
          padding: 0px 0px 8px 0px;     
          <!--0 left padding makes dissapear move padding?-->
        }

        .closebtn {
          color: blue;
          position: absolute;
          right: 25px;
          font-size: 36px;
          margin-left: 50px;
        }
```

```
<svg viewbox="0 0 1200 600" preserveAspectRatio="none">
     <g transform="translate(300,364) scale(16)" >
     <g onclick="openPanelTableA()" >
     <rect style="display:inline; fill: yellow;"     
        width="5" height="3" />
</svg>
```

```
   function openPanelTableA() {
   document.getElementById("mySidePanelTableA").style.width = "250px";}

   function closePanelTableA() {
   document.getElementById("mySidePanelTableA").style.width = "0";}
```

```html
<div id="mySidePanelTableA" class="sidePanelTableA">
      <a href="javascript:void(0)" 
               class="closebtn" 
               onclick="closePanelTableA()">
                  &times;
          </a>
          <br><br>
          TITLE
           <br><br>
       <img src="tableA.jpeg" height="200px">
</div>
```

I expect the red side panel to be completely hidden, but it shows by the width of it's padding on the left of the screen. It is properly hidden if I remove the internal left-side padding from the panel, but then the padding's gone...

Thanks, in advance.

Badly-formatted Codepen: https://codepen.io/moptopop/pen/RwbVMLv in which the effect somehow DOES NOT seem to show on adding left padding.
(Please scroll slightly to click yellow rectangle which should trigger the problem panel. Sorry I wasn't able to add the image back in, but that shouldn't affect the issue.)

Comment: Are you just trying to have a slide panel slide out from the left on a button click with some padding?

Comment: What's stopping you from using an internal wrapper around all panel content and giving that wrapper the padding you want? [Example](https://codepen.io/andrei-gheorghiu/pen/qBWmogJ).

Comment: Yes, Chris. Exactly.

Comment: Updated the above pen. You shouldn't change `width` (because when you animate it you'll get the contents "squashed". You should animate `transform`. See the updated example (same link as above).

Comment: Mr. Gheorghiu, your pen solved it for me! Just had to downsize the picture a bit. So grateful for your -- and everyone else's help!!!

Answer (score 0):

You have two options- either remove he left padding when the menu is "hidden" then reinstate it when it is"shown" - or to apply a `max width:0; overflow:hidden` to the panel when it is "hidden".

Also - it is better to add / remove a class that has the styling in the CSS than to directly add css to an element via javascript.

Note the following code only addresses the width / padding / visibility and not the side transitions etc.

```
//js
function openPanelTableA() {
   document.getElementById("mySidePanelTableA").classList.remove("hide-panel")}

   function closePanelTableA() {
   document.getElementById("mySidePanelTableA").classList.add("hide-panel")}


//css
  #mySidePanelTableA {
   width: 250px;
   padding: 0px 0px 8px 0px;// or whatever padding you want   
  }

  #mySidePanelTableA.hide-panel {
   width: 0;
   max-width: 0;
   overflow: hidden; // this prevents the panel from being seen - even with the padding.
  }
```

Comment: I will look at your solution as well -- Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For the closed state, you have to either:

- give negative left = width + padding
- give padding = width = 0, and then, set padding/width for .open state

here's a code snippet:

```js
function openPanelTableA() {
  document
    .getElementById("mySidePanelTableA")
    .classList.add('open');
}

function closePanelTableA() {
  document
    .getElementById("mySidePanelTableA")
    .classList.remove('open');
}
```

```css
html, body {
  padding: 0;
}

.sidePanelTableA {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  height: 80%;
  position: fixed; 
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: red;
  overflow-x: hidden;


  width: 0;
  padding: 0;
  transition: all ease 0.5s;
}

.sidePanelTableA.open {
  width: 150px;
  padding: 30px;
}

#mysidePanelTableA  {
  padding: 0px 0px 8px 20px;
}

.closebtn {
  color: blue;
  position: absolute;
  right: 25px;
  font-size: 36px;
  margin-left: 50px;
}
```

```html
<div id="mySidePanelTableA" class="sidePanelTableA">
  <a
    href="javascript:void(0)" 
    class="closebtn" 
    onclick="closePanelTableA()"
  >
    &times;
  </a>
  <br /><br />
  TITLE
  <br /><br />
  <img src="tableA.jpeg" height="200px" />
</div>

<button onclick="openPanelTableA()">Open</button>
```

Comment: This may work if the button can be an SVG. If so it seems perfect. Thanks!